# Produce multiple lists from a list of lists in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have some records with the schema below:

```
    (key,[[value1,value2],[value3,value4]])
```

What I would like to do is for each of these records emit:

```
    (key,[value1,value2])
    (key,[value3,value4])
```

using the RDD API in Pyspark.

For one-to-many relationship between input and output I think I could use flatMap but I am not sure how to apply it in this case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `flatMapValues`:

```
rdd2 = rdd.flatMapValues(lambda x: x)
```